# Load log4j from stream

Tags: java, xml

is it possible to load `log4j` configuration from the ByteStream?

or from something else, but not from the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [DOM element](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.html#configure%28org.w3c.dom.Element%29).

Extending the DOMConfigurator perhaps even with [InputStream](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.html#doConfigure%28java.io.InputStream,%20org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggerRepository%29).

Comment: I do not know why I did nto even think about this! Thanks! it works!